# Variable and loops convertion from VB.NET to C++?

Tags: c++, vb.net, context-free-grammar

Is there any available tool for converting variable and loops declarations from VB.NET to C++?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to convert vb.net source to C++ ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113134/is-it-possible-to-convert-vb-net-source-to-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about C++/CLI then you may consider using Reflector.NET to convert VB.NET to C++/CLI. If you're talking about managed/unmanaged bridge then .net framework does that for you (marshalling).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about C++ exactly, but there's a conversion tool which would convert to C# which would be close-ish - though you won't have access to .net framework-specific methods in C++ (unless you're using C++ .Net).

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Answer (score 0):

I'd really doubt it. Unlike VB->C# conversion, VB is a entirely different beast that C++. You don't want to convert VB to C++, you'll end up with a mess of a program.

Rewrite your code in C++ using standard C++ conventions.